# Convert yyyymm String to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss date time in athena

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to convert a string column "yyyymm" to a "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" datetime column in athena.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?:

```
select date_parse(strdatecol,'%b-%d-%Y')
from table
```

Answer (score -1):

date_parse() works perfectly fine in this case. It reads a string value, the format of the string value and then converts that string value to datetime value. In this case, yyyymm was passed as the string and the format was year and month value.

This gave me the result I was looking for:

```
SELECT date_parse('yyyymm', '%Y%m')
```